# Docker container link for mysql to redmine fails with timeout "waiting for database server to accept connections"

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to get my redmine site up and running again. For which we have two docker containers. one contains the database mysql, and the other the website - Redmine.

mysql should be start first

```
     nohup docker run --name  mysql -v /opt/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 7e0828bb2e6e &
    [1] 27673
root@atd-ciso:/# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
8986ecda4c9a        sameersbn/mysql:latest   "/start"            16 hours ago        Up 10 seconds       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   mysql
nohup docker run --name  mysql -v /opt/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 7e0828bb2e6e &
```

But

```
root@atd-ciso:/# tail -f nohup.out
Waiting for database server to accept connections...........................................................
```

The container just outputs this and eventually timesout and stops running. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `nohup` to manually push docker into the background like this? Try detaching with `-d` instead. And, addressing your question, It appears to be timing out waiting for the database to start. See your message at line 50 in the code here: https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-mysql/blob/master/start

Comment: Ok Thanks @Nathaniel,

Since i posted i made a couple of adjustments: 
# docker run --name  mysql -v /opt/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 sammeersbn/mysql:latest
# docker run --name redmine -v /opt/redmine/data:/home/redmine/data -p 82:80 --link mysql:redmine sameersbn/redmine:latest

Which receives a
#ERROR:
#  Please configure the database connection.
#  Refer http://git.io/JkE-cw for more information.
#  Cannot continue without a database. Aborting...

therefore is guess i need the DB_NAME, DB_USER, But my mysql skills  worse than my docker skills, how can i do this?